# var to dynamic is known at compile time?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, var

if we have :

```
dynamic x = "hello"; // Static type is dynamic, runtime type is string
var y = "hello"; // Static type is string, runtime type is string
```

Fine.

what about

```
dynamic x = *veryComplicatedRunTimeStructure_UnknownatCompileTime.*; 
var y=x;
```

it `DOES` compile !

I have a problem with the `second` line here.

it is known that `var` is evaluated in *compile* time.

[image]

But in compile time it *doesn't* have a clue about the type....

so...what is the compile type of the y?

Comment: @DennisTraub edited ( it deleted some how) ...

Comment: `new { t = 3, y = 3 };` is very much known at compile-time. The compiler does have a clue about the type because the compiler just generated it. The programmer does not have a (complete) clue about it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman its just an example. it could have come from a future com object...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the type of the assignment expression is `dynamic`, so is the implicitly declared variable's type. There's nothing special about `dynamic` here - your code is equivalent to:

```
dynamic x = new { t = 3, y = 3 };
dynamic y = x;
```

From section 8.5.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> In the context of a local variable declaration, the identifier `var` acts as a contextual keyword. When the *local-variable-type* is specified as `var` and no type named `var` is in scope, the declaration is an *implicitly typed variable declaration*, whose type is inferred from the type of the associated initializer expression.
>
> [...]
>
> In an implicitly typed local variable declaration, the type of the local variable being
>   declared is taken to be the same as the type of the expression used to initialize the variable.

So here, the expression is `dynamic`, and so is the variable...

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/aeinbu/4718987870/ do you have a link for this video ? Im learning a lot lately about covariance...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I believe you can still download it as part of the NDC 2010 torrent: http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=361621 - alternatively, I cover it in part 25 of my Tekpub series: http://tekpub.com/productions/csharp4

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
dynamic x = new {t = 3; y=3};
var y = x;
```

is equal to:

```
dynamic x = new {t = 3; y=3};
dynamic y = x;
```

so, to answer to your question, the type of `y` is `dynamic`.